# Sequelize - Join with multiple column

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, node-modules

I like to convert the following query into sequelize code

```
select * from table_a 
inner join table_b 
on table_a.column_1 = table_b.column_1
and table_a.column_2 = table_b.column_2
```

I have tried many approaches and followed many provided solution but I am unable to achieve the desired query from sequelize code.

The max I achieve is following :

```
select * from table_a 
inner join table_b 
on table_a.column_1 = table_b.column_1
```

I want the second condition also.

```
and table_a.column_2 = table_b.column_2
```

any proper way to achieve it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to define your own `on` clause of the `JOIN` statement

```
ModelA.findAll({
    include: [
        {
            model: ModelB,
            on: {
                col1: sequelize.where(sequelize.col("ModelA.col1"), "=", sequelize.col("ModelB.col1")),
                col2: sequelize.where(sequelize.col("ModelA.col2"), "=", sequelize.col("ModelB.col2"))
            },
            attributes: [] // empty array means that no column from ModelB will be returned
        }
    ]
}).then((modelAInstances) => {
    // result...
});
```

Comment: Getting error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Comment: What should I write in model file?

Comment: Does this require you to set up any associations on either of the models? I’m looking at doing something very similar. There are no FKs on the tables so not wanting to add any associations if possible. Thanks.

Comment: @TophatGordon I tried to make a solution for one of my use cases. Please check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63830718/8133717) here and see if that helps you.

Answer (score 14):

Regarding @TophatGordon 's doubt in accepted answer's comment: that if we need to have any associations set up in model or not.
Also went through the [github issue raised back in 2012](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/311) that is still in **open** state.
So I was also in the same situation and trying to setup my own `ON` condition for left outer join.
When I directly tried to use the `on: {...}` inside the `Table1.findAll(...include Table2 with ON condition...)`, it didn't work.
It threw an error:

> `EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: Table2 is not associated to Table1!`

My use case was to match two non-primary-key columns from Table1 to two columns in Table2 in left outer join. I will show how and what I acheived:

---

Don't get confused by table names and column names, as I had to change them from the original ones that I used.

SO I had to create an association in Table1(Task) like:

```
Task.associate = (models) => {    

Task.hasOne(models.SubTask, {
        foreignKey: 'someId', // <--- one of the column of table2 - SubTask: not a primary key here in my case; can be primary key also
        sourceKey: 'someId', // <---  one of the column of table1 - Task: not a primary key here in my case; can be a primary key also
        scope: {
            [Op.and]: sequelize.where(sequelize.col("Task.some_id_2"),
                // '=',
                Op.eq, // or you can use '=',
                sequelize.col("subTask.some_id_2")),
        },
        as: 'subTask',
        // no constraints should be applied if sequelize will be creating tables and unique keys are not defined, 
        //as it throws error of unique constraint            
        constraints: false, 
    });
};
```

So the find query looks like this :

```
Task.findAll({
    where: whereCondition,
    // attributes: ['id','name','someId','someId2'],
    include: [{
        model: SubTask, as: 'subTask', // <-- model name and alias name as defined in association 
        attributes: [], // if no attributes needed from SubTask - empty array
    },
    ],
});
```

Resultant query:

- One matching condition is taken from [foreignKey] = [sourceKey]
- Second matching condition is obtained by `sequelize.where(...)` used in `scope:{...}`

> ```
> select
>   "Task"."id",
>   "Task"."name",
>   "Task"."some_id" as "someId",
>   "Task"."some_id_2" as "someId2"
> from
>   "task" as "Task"
> left outer join "sub_task" as "subTask" on
>   "Task"."some_id" = "subTask"."some_id"
>   and "Task"."some_id_2" = "subTask"."some_id_2";
> ```

---

#### Another approach to achieve same as above to solve issues when using Table1 in include i.e. when Table1 appears as 2nd level table or is included from other table - say Table0

```
Task.associate = (models) => {    

Task.hasOne(models.SubTask, {
        foreignKey: 'someId', // <--- one of the column of table2 - SubTask: not a primary key here in my case; can be primary key also
        sourceKey: 'someId', // <---  one of the column of table1 - Task: not a primary key here in my case; can be a primary key also
        as: 'subTask',
        // <-- removed scope -->
        // no constraints should be applied if sequelize will be creating tables and unique keys are not defined, 
        //as it throws error of unique constraint            
        constraints: false, 
    });
};
```

So the find query from Table0 looks like this : *Also the foreignKey and sourceKey will not be considered as we will now use custom `on: {...}`*

```
Table0.findAll({
    where: whereCondition,
    // attributes: ['id','name','someId','someId2'],
    include: {
        model: Task, as: 'Table1AliasName', // if association has been defined as alias name 
        include: [{
            model: SubTask, as: 'subTask', // <-- model name and alias name as defined in association 
            attributes: [], // if no attributes needed from SubTask - empty array
            on: {
                [Op.and]: [
                    sequelize.where(
                        sequelize.col('Table1AliasName_OR_ModelName.some_id'),
                        Op.eq, // '=',
                        sequelize.col('Table1AliasName_OR_ModelName->subTask.some_id')
                    ),
                    sequelize.where(
                        sequelize.col('Table1AliasName_OR_ModelName.some_id_2'),
                        Op.eq, // '=',
                        sequelize.col('Table1AliasName_OR_ModelName->subTask.some_id_2')
                    ),
                ],
            },
        }],
    }
});
```

#### Skip below part if your tables are already created...

---

Set constraints to false, as if sequelize tries to create the 2nd table(SubTask) it might throw error `(DatabaseError [SequelizeDatabaseError]: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "task")` due to following query:

> create table if not exists "sub_task" ("some_id" INTEGER, "some_id_2"
> INTEGER references "task" ("some_id") on delete   cascade on  update
> cascade, "data" INTEGER);

If we set **constraint: false**, it creates this below query instead which will not throw unique constraint error as we are referencing non-primary column:

> create table if not exists "sub_task" ("some_id" INTEGER, "some_id_2" INTEGER, "data" INTEGER);

Comment: Wow... this was REALLY timely, lol. I was just looking for how to accomplish this and BOOM it was answered 6 hours earlier. Thanks @Abhishek Shah!

Comment: @KyleFarris 2 months back I came to this same post and also the [github issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/311) , but there wasn't any specific answer that I got for the problem. And today here I am back with a solution, that might help atleast a little.

Comment: how does this work when `Task` is part of an `as`?  e.g. `user->tasks` because `Task` is nested in an include?

Comment: @Jayen Can you refer the Table0.findAll part of the answer. Does that help?

Comment: yes, thanks.  i ended up using `user->tasks` in `scope` instead of `where` as i have a few similar queries.  using `separate:true` worked as well but for other reasons i couldn't use that.