# Is it possible add extra field in Sequelize relation?

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I have `belongsTo` relation like this:

```
classMethods: {
    associate: function(models) {
        User.belongsTo(models.Prefs, {timestamps: false, foreignKey: 'Type', targetKey: 'UserType'})

    }
}
```

which produces

```
 LEFT OUTER JOIN `prefs` AS `Prefs` ON `User`.`Type` = `Prefs`.`UserType`
```

The problem is that I also need to add extra check like

```
AND `Prefs`.`Section` = 'GLOBAL'
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is duplicate of [Sequelize - Join with multiple column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42226351/sequelize-join-with-multiple-column/42227842#42227842)
.

You need to use custom `ON` condition in the `JOIN` clause

```
User.findAll({
    include: [
        {
            model: Prefs,
            on: {
                Type: db.sequelize.where(db.sequelize.col("User.Type"), "=", db.sequelize.col("Prefs.UserType")),
                Section: 'GLOBAL'
            },
            attributes: [] // do not return any columns of Prefs table
        }
    ]
}).then((users) => {
    // resulting users...
});
```

**EDIT**

I believe [**`scope`**](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#scopes) is what you are looking for. Try adding it to the association

```
classMethods: {
    associate: function(models) {
        User.belongsTo(
            models.Prefs,
            {
                timestamps: false,
                foreignKey: 'Type',
                targetKey: 'UserType',
                scope: { Section: 'GLOBAL' }
            }
        );
    }    
}
```

Comment: I need to specify this in model class

Comment: I updated the answer, I hope this one will help you.