# Sequelize V6 - Join with multiple column

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

**I like to convert the following query into sequelize code version 6**

```
select * from table_a 
inner join table_b 
on table_a.column_1 = table_b.column_1
and table_a.column_2 = table_b.column_2
```

**I have tried many approaches and followed many provided solution but I am unable to achieve the desired query from sequelize code.**

**The max I achieve is following :**

```
select * from table_a 
inner join table_b 
on table_a.column_1 = table_b.column_1
```

**I want the second condition also.**

```
and table_a.column_2 = table_b.column_2
```

**any proper way to achieve it?**

**EDIT :**

**Resultant will look like this :**

```
dbo.Unit_Activity INNER JOIN
dbo.Activities AS A ON dbo.Unit_Activity.Sub_Activity_Code = A.Activity_Code INNER JOIN
dbo.Activities AS B ON dbo.Unit_Activity.Activity_Code = B.Activity_Code INNER JOIN
dbo.Employee_Roles ON dbo.Unit_Activity.Unit_ID = dbo.Employee_Roles.Unit_ID AND dbo.Unit_Activity.Role_Code = dbo.Employee_Roles.Role_Code
```

**I have tried this so far**

```
 Activities.hasMany(UnitActivity, { foreignKey: 'Sub_Activity_Code' });            
 EmployeeRoles.hasMany(UnitActivity, { foreignKey: 'Unit_ID', required: true  }, {foreignKey: 'Role_Code', required: true });           
 UnitActivity.belongsTo(Activities, { foreignKey: 'Sub_Activity_Code', targetKey: 'Activity_Code' }); 
 UnitActivity.belongsTo(EmployeeRoles, { foreignKey: 'Unit_ID', targetKey: 'Unit_ID' }); 
     

    var act = await UnitActivity.findAll({attributes: ['Sub_Activity_Code'],
        include: [
             { model: Activities, attributes: ['Activity_Code'], required: true }, 
             { model: EmployeeRoles, attributes: ['Role_Code'], required: true } 
       ]                
     })
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post some of your Sequelize code so that we can see what's wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42226351/sequelize-join-with-multiple-column

Comment: I am working on Sequelize v6

Comment: Tsvetan Ganev Question Edited